# How to set a mesh with a material to actor in C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

How to set a mesh with a material to actor AMySphere?

```
void AMyActor::DrawSpheresAtLevel(int level_)
{
    // 1. Generate parameters...
    if (0 != level_)
    {
        spheres_count += spheres_count / 100 * factor;
        radius += radius / 100 * rad_factor; // radius of a circle with a player placed at the center
    }
    // 2. Generate spheres.
    FVector location;
    GetPlayerLocation(location);
    float x = location.X + radius;
    FVector previous_scenter;
    for (int j = 0; j <= spheres_count; ++j)
    {
        float y = std::sqrt(pow(radius, 2) - pow(x, 2));
        FVector sphere_center = { x, y, 100 };
        
        FRotator rot = FRotator::ZeroRotator;
        if (j != 0) // calculate distance between previous sphere and current sphere 
        {           // centers until it becomes less, or equal to 80
            float deg = 1.f;
            do
            {
                rot.SetComponentForAxis(EAxis::Type::Z, deg++);
                sphere_center = rot.RotateVector(previous_scenter);
            } while (Distance(previous_scenter, sphere_center) < 80.f);
        }
        // Draw a sphere.
        FActorSpawnParameters SpawnParams;
        AMySphere* sphere_ptr = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AMySphere>(sphere_center, rot, SpawnParams);
        if (nullptr == sphere_ptr)
        {
            std::cout << "nullptr\n";
        }
        else
        {
            sphere_ptr->SetObserver(this);
            sphere_ptr->SetIndex_(spheres.size());
            spheres.push_back(sphere_ptr);
        }
        previous_scenter = sphere_center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just a sphere you can add a component like this in `AMySphere::AMySphere` and add whatever material you want to this component.

```
USphereComponent* SphereComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USphereComponent>(TEXT("RootComponent"));
RootComponent = SphereComponent;
SphereComponent->InitSphereRadius(40.0f);
```

If you want to change mesh you can create `UStaticMeshComponent` instead and assign mesh asset to it runtime.

Comment: I want to make AMySphere object visible in my scene. What is required for this?

Comment: Make sure the sphere is of the proper size and is spawn in the proper place, visible flag is set to true and material is not of invisible kind.

You can debug the result of the spawn when playing in editor just set some name tho the new actor and search in the scene tree for it to see the state of what was spawned